# Footnotes: Label in paragraph, text somewhere else?

Tags: lyx, footnotes

TL;DR: Is there a package that allows writing the
text of a footnote after the position where the
mark should be inserted? Note that I'm asking
about positioning of source code, *not* about
positioning of the note in the output document.

---

When writing LaTeX I find the inline character of
footnote source somewhat distracting.

```
This is some text\footnote{That for
whatever reason contains a long 
footnote. The main text becomes split 
apart} so far that it is barely readable.
```

Doing tricks with newlines like

```
This is some text\footnote{
  That for whatever reason contains a long
  footnote. The main text becomes split
  apart}
so far that it is barely readable.
```

Also helps only so much. I'd much prefer to write

```
This is some text\fn{1} that contains a
couple\fn{2} footnotes yet remain readable.

\text{1}{Here is the text of the first
footnote, conveniently readable while reading
the main source, yet not disrupting it.}

\text{2}{-/2}
```

I know that some tricks are possible with
`\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`. When having
more than one footnote in a paragraph however this
would require manually changing the footnote
counter, which is too inconvenient to make this a
sensible alternative. Also if I'm not mistaken, it
carries the risk of causing footnotes to be
displayed on the wrong page, when the paragraph
stretches to the next page but the `\footnotemark`
is in text on the current page.

```
+---------------+  +---------------+
|...            |  |end of the page|
|               |  |...            |
|               |  |               |
|some text with²|  |—————          |
|footnote on the|  |²The FNText    |
+---------------+  +---------------+
```

Is there maybe some package that automates such a
style?

As a quick hack I sometimes used constructs like

```
\def\fnlater#1#2{\def#1{\footnote{#2}}}
...
\fnlater\myfnI{The footnote text must be
defined before the paragraph.}
...
Here is some textparagraph\myfnI that refers
to the previously defined footnote.
```

Sadly this custom solution has two major flaws:

1. It requires defining the footnote *before*
   using it, while intuitively footnotes are expected
   *after* the surrounding text.
2. It should cause a compilation error, when the
   footnote is accidentially used twice.
3. It should also cause a compilation error, when
   the footnote isn't used at all.

Since I don't think that these issues are easily
fixed, especially the requirement to define the
footnote before the surrounding text, using custom
hacks is undesireable.

If such a package exists for LaTeX, availability of a
corresponding module for LyX would be even better.

---

As a minimal compileable example put any of these
code examples into a skeleton

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: LyX already provide this functionality in its editor; that is, to code-fold a footnote so it's not distracting you from reading the footnote mid-text. Just click on `foot 1`. I assume you're asking whether an additional package that does this sort of magic should be used by a LyX module rather than the default footnote module.

Comment: I know, but its insufficient. I need to SEE the footnote (without folding and unfolding all the time), yet also not to disturb the main text too much. But yes, if there is such a LaTeX package, I'd like to also have a module in LyX that enables that package with insets. Though such a module would probably be easier to write than the corresponding LaTeX package, which likely would need auxilliary-file magic.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to put this together. <strike>It only allows clear text in the footer, but apart from that</strike> it should do all you wanted. No error is raised if a label is undefined, however, as that would give an error every time a new footnote is added.

**Edit:** Now it supports formatting thanks to `\detokenize` :D

Footnotes are defined anywhere in the document with `\definefootnote{label}{footnotetext}` and used anywhere else in the document with `\usefootnote{label}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\catcode`#=11
\AtEndDocument{
\immediate\write\@auxout{\detokenize{%
    \newcommand{\@makefootnote}[2]%
        {\expandafter\gdef\csname footnote@#1\endcsname{#2}%
        % Check if footnote is unused
        \AtEndDocument%
            {\expandafter\ifx\csname footnoteused@#1\endcsname\relax%
                \errmessage{Error: Footnote #1 never used!}%
            \fi}}}}}
\catcode`#=6

\newcommand{\@addfootnotetolist}[2]
    {\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout
        {\detokenize{\@makefootnote{#1}{#2}}}}}

\newcommand{\definefootnote}[2]
    {% Check if footnote has been defined earlier
    \expandafter\ifx\csname footnotedefd@#1\endcsname\relax
        \@addfootnotetolist{#1}{#2}%
        \expandafter\def\csname footnotedefd@#1\endcsname{}%
    \else
        \errmessage{Error: Footnote #1 defined twice!}
    \fi}
\newcommand{\usefootnote}[1]
    {% Check if footnote is defined
    \expandafter\ifx\csname footnote@#1\endcsname\relax
        % not yet defined, give warning?
        % always happens first time used, of course
        \expandafter\def\csname footnoteused@#1\endcsname{}%
    \else
        % Check if footnote has been used
        \expandafter\ifx\csname footnoteused@#1\endcsname\relax
            \footnote{\csname footnote@#1\endcsname}%
            \expandafter\def\csname footnoteused@#1\endcsname{}%
        \else
            \errmessage{Error: Footnote #1 used twice!}
        \fi
    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

text\usefootnote{label}

\definefootnote{label}{footnotetext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \immediate\write18 ?

Comment: That didn't work :/

Comment: `\newrobustcmd{\WriteNow}{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string <stuff to write>}}` I used something like this.. but I always use counters so I don't know about actual name tags

Comment: I got the aux file working :D (Although only in \AtEndDocument)

Comment: But bottom line "there is no such package"? I want to avoid "per file" solutions, since there's a good chance that they cause me to not understand my own documents later. Otherwise though, it is  a very educational example :) With some counter usage one may make labels obsolete too and raise an error when the number of used and defined footnotes doesn't match up at the end of e.g. a section.

Answer (score 0):

Jonas,

When I tried your MVW footnote macros, from your May 27, 2014 post, it stopped working after I added in a second reference, via \usefootnote{label}, to the same footnote.  The error manifested itself during the second run of pdflatex, as follows:

\usefootnote ...e {Error: Footnote #1 used twice!}
\fi \fi
l.49 ...s the second occurrence\usefootnote{label}
.
?

I was under the impression that your macros would facilitate a situation where there could be two points on the page which happen to reference the same footnote (i.e. a single footnote which is shared).

For the avoidance of doubt, I include below the MWE (which has that one additional footnote reference) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\catcode`#=11
\AtEndDocument{
\immediate\write\@auxout{\detokenize{%
    \newcommand{\@makefootnote}[2]%
        {\expandafter\gdef\csname footnote@#1\endcsname{#2}%
        % Check if footnote is unused
        \AtEndDocument%
            {\expandafter\ifx\csname footnoteused@#1\endcsname\relax%
                \errmessage{Error: Footnote #1 never used!}%
            \fi}}}}}
\catcode`#=6

\newcommand{\@addfootnotetolist}[2]
    {\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout
        {\detokenize{\@makefootnote{#1}{#2}}}}}

\newcommand{\definefootnote}[2]
    {% Check if footnote has been defined earlier
    \expandafter\ifx\csname footnotedefd@#1\endcsname\relax
        \@addfootnotetolist{#1}{#2}%
        \expandafter\def\csname footnotedefd@#1\endcsname{}%
    \else
        \errmessage{Error: Footnote #1 defined twice!}
    \fi}
\newcommand{\usefootnote}[1]
    {% Check if footnote is defined
    \expandafter\ifx\csname footnote@#1\endcsname\relax
        % not yet defined, give warning?
        % always happens first time used, of course
        \expandafter\def\csname footnoteused@#1\endcsname{}%
    \else
        % Check if footnote has been used
        \expandafter\ifx\csname footnoteused@#1\endcsname\relax
            \footnote{\csname footnote@#1\endcsname}%
            \expandafter\def\csname footnoteused@#1\endcsname{}%
        \else
            \errmessage{Error: Footnote #1 used twice!}
        \fi
    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

text\usefootnote{label}.

This is the second occurrence\usefootnote{label}.

\definefootnote{label}{footnotetext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).