# footnotes and bottom in editor?

Tags: footnotes, editors

I have a lot of footnotes and it is distracting while trying to read the document in the editor. Is there a way to hide the footnotes or have them appear at the bottom of the page in the editor?
thanks

Comment: Hi Heather, welcome to the site! It'd be great if you could provide a few more details, as [there are quite a few editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) available.

Comment: Certainly possible in AUCTeX `;)`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144943/footnote-non-inline-syntax and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180672/footnotes-label-in-paragraph-text-somewhere-else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer but doesn't fit in comments. One thing that can help is to format the footnotes in your source code in a way that sets them apart from the main text somewhat. I try to put all footnotes at the end of a sentence (I use a notes-and-bibliography style). I put these notes on a separate line in the source code, surrounded by comment marks and sometimes indented. For example:

```
Two authors have written about this topic.%
   %
   \footnote{I can cite both authors with one note here: \autocites{First}{Second}.}
   %
Here the main text continues.
```

If you do this, make sure you don't forget the comment mark at the end of the first sentence; otherwise you get a space before the footnote number.